# Finding the volume of a solid made with base as a parabola.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> The base of the solid is the region between the $x$-axis and the parabola $y=4-x^2$. The vertical cross sections of the solid perpendicular to the $y$-axis are semicircles. Compute the volume of the solid.

I know the area formula for a semicircle is $\frac{(\pi*r^2)}{2}$, but would you use $r=4 - x^2$ even though the question only says the base is made from this parabola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each semicircle has a radius $x$, so the solid has volume

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^2 dy \, x^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^2 dy \, (4-y) = 3 \pi$$

Comment: Ron - why do you integrate from 0 to 2 rather than -2 to 2?

Comment: @mathtastic: "The base of the solid is the region between the x-axis and the parabola $y=4-x^2$..."

Comment: But doesn't 4-x^2 intercept the x-axis at 2 and -2? - Ron

Comment: lol - woops. I just noticed your differential.

Comment: @ Bryce - you made the same mistake I did and just assumed he used $dx$. Instead, he uses the differential $dy$ and notice $y=4-x^2$ becomes $x=\sqrt{4-y}$ so that, when plugged into the formula you indicated in your post, you obtain Ron's integral.

Comment: @mathtastic - Thanks, I understand where I went wrong now! Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is c-lower limit and d-upper limit integral of A(y) dy .The limits of integration are wrong since you're integrating with respect to y the limits should be 0 to 4 and the ans is 4pi ---for more explanation look up Volume - Cross Sections Perpendicular to the y-axis on youtube. The radius needs to be in terms of y because the cross sections are perpendicular to the y-axis so you solve for x and get +and-sqrt(4-y) and you subtract the positive square root from the negative square root and divide by 2 because you want radius, not diameter then square it and that's how you get (4-y).